# Remove a mailbox and add a new one

Tags: email, exchange

I am experiencing the issue of walking into a new company as a sysadmin and no one has looked after their exchange for a long time.
Because of that there is a mailbox (Lets call it Mailer) that is around 1TB now and gets around 9000 e-mails a day.
It is the only mailbox in a database (edb) but due to its size I am struggling to do anything with it.
I have tried PowerShell export to PST commands (New-MailboxExportRequest), even running it in a months cut off it takes up to 5 days to run (Running PowerShell on a local PC as when I did it in the Exchange server it became unresponsive)
While the Export command is running[,](https://dreamleaguesoccer.pw/dream-league-soccer-classic-apk/) we are getting a heap of "E-mail delayed" notifications coming out of that account to customers (Really bad thing).
So my new theory is, create a new mail database, in that create a new mailbox. Then somehow tell my mail account (Lets call it Mailer) to use that mailbox instead of the huge one.
The only issue is I have no idea how to achieve this, or if it is even possible. Any help would be great.

Comment: Hi, Do you auto archive old email ? and does someone actualy read those 9000 emails a days ? if no, you have cleanup to do there

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, If you want senders send emails to a new mailbox, you can configure a transport rule. For example, open EMC and select create a new rule, apply this rule if the recipient is Mailer, do the following redirect the message to a new mailbox.

Secondly, you can configure inbox rule, use an auto-reply template to alert senders to send mails to a new mailbox (in auto-reply templete, you should tell senders that they should send mails to this new mailbox)

Combined with these two rules, the message can reach both the new mailbox and the sender will send the message to the new mailbox next time.

Auto-reply:[Outlook rule: “reply using a specific template”](https://www.outlook-apps.com/outlook-reply-template/)

Note: When using an auto-response template, the same sender will only receive an auto-reply.